# How to extract xpath list in camel

Tags: java, xpath, apache-camel

My requirement is as below:

1. I have a properties file which has values as:
   `/message/header/messagetype ='DATA'`
2. So the XPaths are the keys and the values are the dates I want to check in Camel at runtime

I read an ActiveMQ queue which gets me an XML message. Now at runtime I need to check the respective XPaths from the properties file and check there respective values in the XML message I get from the queue. There could be any number of XPath checks defined in the properties file. This is defined by the business needs and the code should take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to read a properties file and "transform" it to XPath checks. However, you can always use a plain Java Bean and call it from your Camel route. For example like this:

```
from()
...
.bean(YourBean.class)
...
```

With this you can use Java code as a "component" in your Camel route.

For more details see the Camel docs about [Bean binding](http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html) and the [Bean component](http://camel.apache.org/bean.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help. I figured out how to do this by using Predicate functionality in Camel.So what I am doing now is, creating multiple Predicate objects based on my property file entries and adding them to 'PredicateBuilder' as below ::

`PredicateBuilder.and(p1,p2....pn);`

This returns me an object of Predicate which I can use in when() of Camel.

for eg.  `choice().
        when(predicateBuilder()).`